# Assessing whether differences between datasets are significant

Tags: statistical-significance, proportion

I am unsure which statistical test I should use to test whether two datasets are significantly different. The data looks something like this:

```
Group   Dataset 1   Dataset 2
A   5   6
B   1   7
C   2   10
D   1   15
E   4   11
F   1   5
G   2   17
H   2   10
I   3   19
J   1   6
K   14  67
L   13  38
M   3   16
N   14  59
O   14  33
P   0   4
Q   10  28
R   0   6
S   4   9
T   3   5
U   3   13
V   0   13
```

I am hoping that, although one dataset has a larger sum, the proportions between groups mean that they are not significantly different.

Does anybody have any helpful advice or suggestions of a suitable test? Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) are the data paired?   (2) Your values there are integers. What are the values? Are they counts?   (3) There are many ways distributions might differ. What kinds of differences are you interested in?

Comment: The groups represent gene classifications. So, each value is a count representing a gene which falls into that classification. The two datasets are different groups of genes, and I want to find whether the datsets are significantly different based on how the genes fall into these groups (I ideally don't want them to be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're after a test of homogeneity (i.e. whether the proportions in each classification are the same across the two groups of genes).

The usual way to do this is a via a chi-squared test.

Below are the results from performing (in R) the chi-squared test against the usual chi-squared distribution, and by simulating the distribution of the test statistic (conditional on the margins).

The common rule of requiring all expected values greater than 5 is usually too stringent, and it seems to have been the case here; the simulated p-value is essentially the same.

Using chi-squared distribution:

```
> chisq.test(genecl[,2:3])

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  genecl[, 2:3]
X-squared = 22.4867, df = 21, p-value = 0.3719

Warning message:
In chisq.test(genecl[, 2:3]) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Simulated:

```
> chisq.test(genecl[,2:3],simulate=TRUE,B=100000)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 1e+05 replicates)

data:  genecl[, 2:3]
X-squared = 22.4867, df = NA, p-value = 0.3704
```

In either case the proportions in each classification are not sufficiently different to indicate a difference in the distribution across classifications.