# What is the best method to compare two populations within a bigger group?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, multiple-comparisons, group-differences

I have a data frame with two columns:

- rows correspond to different people,
- one column is the country of the respondent. This is a categorical variable,
- the other column is the yes/no answer to the question whether the respondent has a car.

In total I have 2,000 observations, but there are two specific countries which I would like to compare. From one of them I have only 40 respondents and from the other 25. I have calculated "naively" the probability estimates $$P( \text{person } X \text{ has a car } | \text{ person } X \text{ is from country } A),$$ but I do not think that we can compare them directly – as the sample sizes are small, these estimates could be affected by a significant error.

Is there any method to compare the difference between these two populations? I know that people use chi-squared (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159239/what-is-a-good-test-for-comparing-frequency-counts-between-two-groups) and [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110368/assessing-whether-differences-between-datasets-are-significant)), but these methods do not show *how big the difference* is nor they *use the auxiliary information about the whole population consisting of 2,000 observations*.